# d3js forced directed cannot read from json

Tags: json, d3.js

I have a simple json file which is :

```
{
 "nodes":[ 
{"name":"Moe","group":1},
{"name":"Madih1","group":1},
{"name":"Madih2","group":1},
{"name":"Nora","group":1},
{"name":"Myna","group":1}
 ],
 "links":[
{"source":35,"target":44,"value":1},
{"source":44,"target":35,"value":1},
{"source":45,"target":35,"value":1},
{"source":45,"target":44,"value":1},
{"source":35,"target":49,"value":1},
{"source":49,"target":35,"value":1}
 ] 
 }
```

when I save it use exactly the html code as shown in http://bl.ocks.org/4062045#index.html and address the above json, nothing appears on the cancas.

I appreciate it if you help me with this one as I am not very familiar with it. Moreover, it would be great if I know the minimum code required for drawing a graph like this using json.

Best,

Comment: for someone like myself who has the same problem, the node IDs has to start from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of "source" and "target" refer to the index of the item in nodes array.
So you can change your json to following:

```
{
 "nodes":[ 
    {"name":"Moe","group":1},
    {"name":"Madih1","group":1},
    {"name":"Madih2","group":1},
    {"name":"Nora","group":1},
    {"name":"Myna","group":1}
 ],
 "links":[
    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
    {"source":1,"target":2,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":3,"value":1},
    {"source":3,"target":4,"value":1},
 ] 
 }
```

Then you can just copy the codes from http://bl.ocks.org/4062045#index.html example as the minimum code.
Remenber to change the json file to your own json file.

```
d3.json("path/to/your/json", function(error, graph) {
    //codes
});
```